# Specified path for unstripped native libs is not a directory - generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics, google-fabric

**How I can define `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` paths with new Firebase Crashlytics SDK?**

When I try to run:
`./gradlew clean assembleRelease uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease`

I get next error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Specified path for unstripped native libs is not a directory: /Users/martin/repos/example-app-android/app/obj
```

If I manually move all my NDK libs to `./app` folder I get the same error with different path:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Specified path for stripped native libs is not a directory: /Users/martin/repos/example-app-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol/release
```

**In this second case the build command sometimes fails, sometimes not.**

This issue started to appear after I moved from Fabric Crashlytics plugin to Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
In the Fabric case, I had the option to define: `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` paths.
Is that missing in the new Firebase plugin?

Relevant Code:

Old code example:

```
    crashlytics {
        enableNdk true
        androidNdkOut "$buildDir/ndklibs/obj"
        androidNdkLibsOut "$buildDir/ndklibs/libs"
    }
```

New Code example:

```
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true

            }
```

Comment: Hi, could you restructure the question title, for ease of understanding, and do make it specific.

Comment: Updated, I hope it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 8):

I got answer on this link in a meantime:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1199#issuecomment-584680918

> In the new Firebase Crashlytics plugin, the androidNdkOut and androidNdkLibsOut properties have been changed to strippedNativeLibsDir and unstrippedNativeLibsDir, and should be declared in firebaseCrashlytics within the variant block, where you declared nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true.

There is still the issue with the paths itself, you need to set relative paths for the `strippedNativeLibsDir` and `unstrippedNativeLibsDir` to your `/app` directory.
Example:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1199#issuecomment-585262965

Answer (score 0):

Provided by topic starter New Code example is not working in my case, crashing during build with exception: "Crashlytics could not determine unstripped native library directories for project"

Working code is:

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
    nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
    strippedNativeLibsDir "build/ndklibs/obj"
    unstrippedNativeLibsDir "build/ndklibs/libs"
}
```